# Isolator circuit for irrigation controllers sharing a common field ground

Tags: circuit-design, isolation

I'm attempting to add a second irrigation controller to my sprinkler system, however the controller doesn't have an expansion board, so I have to add a second whole controller to the mix. The zones all share a common ground and I'm trying to isolate that ground wire so when one controller is in use, the other controller would be disconnected from the common ground. There's an existing product for this, but it's rather pricey for what seems like it should be a pretty simple circuit.

Everything in the irrigation system runs on 24 V AC

When the "Master Valve" of one of the controllers is activated, it should disconnect the common ground from the other controller. When both master valves are active, only the one that was activated first should have the common ground available to it. Each controller has it's own power supply to supply the 24 V AC.

My questions are, does this circuit design work like I want it to? And is there a better way to do this with some other component besides relays?

I'm using a Rachio 3 controller, and specifically [these instructions on having 2 at the same time](https://support.rachio.com/en_us/how-do-i-wire-one-master-valve-pump-or-common-wire-to-two-controllers-BkhiPIJFD).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRCiXS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is the motivation to disconnect the common ground? This sounds absurd to me.

Comment: @Jens without it you have a ground loop with both controllers having a path to ground. Wouldn't that introduce issues?

Comment: I can't imagine an issue. Where do your worries come from? Can you provide a link to the controller?

Comment: I could not find any useful datasheet of the controller and it's connectivity except the bare connection diagram for the valves and sensors. I think there is no need for a field common grounded at all. This isolator is only useful if you want to enable the same pump from different controllers.

Comment: So the field common is for all the solenoid valves for the sprinkler system. They are already in the ground and wired up and share a common ground that comes back to the controller. The controller opens a solenoid via the dedicated solenoid's wire, and the common ground. If I have 2 different controllers, with two different power supplies providing the 24v AC, but a shared neutral, would that cause an issue?

Comment: I dont' think so